# How do I file a bug on a PPA upstream with the maintainers?

Tags: ppa, vlc, bug-reporting

I want to know what exact steps needs to be done to file a bug on the VLC 3.0 PPA, upstream. I can't figure this out. Here is the [bug listings](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~videolan). Where do I file the bug on it?

Comment: Mail the ppa maintainer

Comment: I've tried [that on multiple occasions](https://launchpad.net/~rdenis/+contactuser) using the little form, is that all that we can do?  Launchpad doesn't have a bugtracker for PPAs?

Comment: depends but generally not. The ppa are user maintained. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/179873

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. If you can add this in a question, I'll upvote and mark as accepted.

Comment: I think this is a parent question. But, I'm ok with duping it over. What a mess, I wonder how many emails this guy must get from this? I assume hundreds.

Comment: Thank you, but IMO probably better to mark this as a duplicate.